# C++Builder is moving objects when vector's capacity is changed, even if it shouldn't

Tags: c++, c++builder, move-semantics

I'm trying to understand move semantics in C++ a little bit better.

First, I tried my code at https://wandbox.org, then I tried it in C++Builder, and I'm confused with the results.

Here's the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>

static int createCount{0};
static int copyCount{0};
static int moveCount{0};

struct Person
{
    std::string name{};

    Person(std::string name)
    : name(std::move(name))
    {
        ++createCount;
        //std::cout << "Created Person \"" << this->name << "\"\n";
    };

    Person(const Person &person)
    : name(person.name)
    {
        ++copyCount;
        //std::cout << "Copied Person \"" << this->name << "\"\n";
    }

    Person(Person &&person) noexcept
    : name(std::move(person.name))
    {
        ++moveCount;
        //std::cout << "Moved Person \"" << this->name << "\"\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::vector<Person> v{};
    for(size_t anzahl = 0; anzahl < 50000; ++anzahl)
        v.emplace_back("Mustermann" + std::to_string(anzahl));

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Created: " << createCount << "\n";
    std::cout << "Copied: " << copyCount << "\n";
    std::cout << "Moved: " << moveCount << "\n";
    std::cout << "Time difference = " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count() << "ms" << std::endl;

    createCount = 0;
    copyCount = 0;
    moveCount = 0;
}
```

As expected, the above code does 50.000 creations and 65.535 moves when run in wandbox. If I remove the `noexcept` keyword from the move constructor, there are 50.000 creations and 65.535 copies. Everything worked as expected.

Then I tried the same code in C++Builder (11.3), and as soon as the move constructor is present, no copies are made. Regardless of whether the `noexcept` keyword is present or not.

I know that the Embarcadero clang compiler has a few enhancements, but it seems a little bit weird to me that something that is defined in the standard is changed. The only thing that I can imagine is that the Embarcadero compiler adds an implicit `noexcept`.

Throwing an exception within the move constructor doesn't have any effect.

Does anyone know what the problem is (or could be)?

Comment: First you could replace v.push_back(Person{"Mustermann" + std::to_string(anzahl)}); with v.emplace_back("Mustermann" + std::to_string(anzahl)); to get rid of 50000 moves. After that you could throw a exception in the move constructor and check if the exception guarantee is fulfilled.

Comment: @Lukas-T Yes you are right, it should be `noexcept` instead of `noexplicit`

@gerum Yes, emplace_back reduces the move operations. Throwing an exception in the move-operator doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @Chris_272 "*it seems a little bit weird to me that something that is defined in the standard is changed*" - what exactly in the standard do you think is being changed here? Why do you think the compiler would fall back to making copies when moves are more efficient? [According to cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), `vector::emplace_back()` is allowed to use a non-`noexcept` move constructor.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I'm not expecting that `emplace back` is making copies. But when the size of the vector is changed expect, that copies are made if move constructor is not `noexcept`. As far as i know when the size of the vector increases the move constructor have to be `noexcept`.